# Cannot see any response headers in http response of Angular 8

Tags: angular, browser, download, http-headers, cors

I was trying to download a csv file that is sent as byte-array from the server when I realized that my http response contain no headers at all. I was expecting a 'content-disposition' header in my response.

Previously, I have been working only with JSON response and hence never bothered to look for headers.

I have gone through many of the answers on SO which resolve similar issue. However, unlike most of the OPs, I am passing 'content-disposition' header from the server and has also exposed the same.

This is how the header map looks on browser which clearly shows the header set and exposed properly

[image]

Even with this response from server, all I get in my subscribe block is the json data in case of json request and Blob  object in case of blob request. NO headers are seen at all.

I have also ensured that no response interceptors are placed in my code which might extract the headers away.

Below is a bit of code I am using:

```
downloadFile(entity: string) {
      return this.http.get(ApiUrlConstants.API_URL.PRICING_CSV_DOWNLOAD_URL + entity,
          { responseType: 'blob' }); // tried with arraybuffer too
}
```

and the below method is called from subscribe after data is received. This is where I am expecting headers

```
 public processBlobResponse(data: any): void {
const blob = new Blob([data._body], { type: data.headers.get('Content-Type') });
const contentDispositionHeader = data.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
if (contentDispositionHeader !== null) {
  const contentDispositionHeaderResult = contentDispositionHeader.split(';')[1].trim().split('=')[1];
  const contentDispositionFileName = contentDispositionHeaderResult.replace(/"/g, '');

  const downloadlink = document.createElement('a');
  downloadlink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  downloadlink.download = contentDispositionFileName;
  if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, contentDispositionFileName);
  } else {
    downloadlink.click();
  }
}
```

}

I am pretty sure I am missing something. Any ideas ?

Comment: Add `observe: 'response'` to your options: `{ responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response' }`

Comment: @David This fixed the issue for me. While, I am sure it should have been easy to find out in docs; I am surprised not even one of the many answers I visited signaled at this.

Comment: @David Will appreciate if you could post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

Add `{observe: 'response'}` to your http options

**Explanation**

From the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-data-from-a-server)

> Important options include the observe and responseType properties.
>
> - The observe option specifies how much of the response to return.
> - The responseType option specifies the format in which to return data.

By default, angular will use `{observe: 'body', responseType: 'json'}` for http options, meaning that angular will only let you access the response's body, automatically turned into a json object, but not the headers.

If you need to access headers returned by the server, you need to specify `observe: 'response'` in the http options ([documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response))

**Note**: When CORS is involved, a requirement to access non standard headers is to specify the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)) server side, e.g.

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Disposition, Authorization, MyCustomHeader
```